# Cannot use "Chrome.storage.sync.set" to update key:value pair

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**Background:**

Hi I am using chrome.storage in my chrome extension. The situation is that I might initiate a key:value pair, then I might need to modify the value of the existing key.

**So I wrote the following code to test if I can modify existing key:**

```
var obj = {};
obj['website_name'] = 'test1';
chrome.storage.sync.set(obj, function(){
  chrome.storage.sync.get('website_name', function(data){
    console.log('1st website_name: ', data);
  });
});
obj['website_name'] = 'test2';
chrome.storage.sync.set(obj, function(){
  chrome.storage.sync.get('website_name', function(data){
    console.log('2nd website_name: ', data);
  });
});
```

**Here is what console.log shows:**

Both line shows the key:value pair is website_name:test2, weird.

[image]

Would someone pls tell me if there is anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've posted it should be clear that the value of the key is being modified. Initially you set it equal to `"test 1"` and then over-write it to be equal to `"test 2"`.

You can double check this by executing the two blocks of your code separately.

Your first block of code...

```
obj['website_name'] = 'test1';
chrome.storage.sync.set(obj, function(){
  chrome.storage.sync.get('website_name', function(data){
    console.log('1st website_name: ', data);
  });
});
```

Logs "test 1" to the console.

And your second block of code...

```
obj['website_name'] = 'test2';
chrome.storage.sync.set(obj, function(){
  chrome.storage.sync.get('website_name', function(data){
    console.log('2nd website_name: ', data);
  });
});
```

Logs "test 2" to the console.

So why then, when you execute all of that code in one go, does "test 2" get printed twice?

It's because the local storage API for chrome extensions is asynchronous. Basically what's happening is that the second block of code over-writes the value of `website_name` before the first block of code is able to retrieve it. Thus, by the time the first block of code gets the key, it has already been overwritten and set equal to `"test 2"`, and so "test 2" is logged to the console twice.

You can check that this is correct by wrapping the second block of code in a `setTimeout`.

```
var obj = {};
obj['website_name'] = 'test1';
chrome.storage.sync.set(obj, function(){
  chrome.storage.sync.get('website_name', function(data){
    console.log('1st website_name: ', data);
  });
});

setTimeout(function() {
  obj['website_name'] = 'test2';
  chrome.storage.sync.set(obj, function(){
    chrome.storage.sync.get('website_name', function(data){
      console.log('2nd website_name: ', data);
    });
  });
}, 500);
```

This delays the execution of the second block of code by half a second-- enough time to illustrate what I have described above.

Your console will now show "test 1" and then "test 2."

In reality, you won't wrap the second block of code in `setTimeout`. It's generally quite unlikely that you will need to store one value, then retrieve it immediately afterwards, and then immediately reset it. If there is even half a second between storing the first key, and then overwriting it, your code will work perfectly.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did setTimeOut and everything works fine!